# How to handle errors in each promise inside the promise all ( without stop executing other promises )

Tags: javascript, promise

I have two API calls inside my method and i decided to use promise all to execute those and wait the method until finishing the API calls.

```
Test() {
  promise.all([getFoo(), getBar()])
    .then()
    .catch();
  -- --some other things
}
```

And when i handle the errors in promiseAll it will come to the catch phase even only one Api call failed. But i need to continue executing 2nd API call even 1st API call failed.( by handling Each promise individually) How can i do that ?